# Create a new sheet within loop and copies data

Tags: vba, excel, loops

[image]

I am trying to create a vba code that can copy data whilst in a loop and copy the data (created through the loop) into a new sheet(s). (I am completely new to vba, any advice is welcome, thank you!)

More specifically I am doing this for Football teams Poisson calculations. The attached sheet shows the tables I am using.

```
Sub Pos()

 Dim k As Long
   For k = 1 To 20
     For l = 1 To 20
       For i = 0 To 10
         For j = 0 To 10
           Cells(75 + i, 3 + j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Poisson_Dist(i, Cells(25 + k, l + 1), False) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Poisson_Dist(j, Cells(50 + k, l + 1), False)
         Next j
       Next i
     Next l
   Next k
End Sub
```

The bottom table is where the problem arises with the code written above. When I press run, it calculates the results but is constantly changing. Is there any way I can get it to copy and paste each result through each iteration.

Comment: Have you tried any code to copy sheets or looked up any code on that yet?

Comment: "When I press run, it calculates the results but is constantly changing. "
- Can you give an example of this to help us understand the problem?

Comment: @Chrismas007 I have looked up codes to copy sheets but I have only found codes which only copy specific ranges or just add new sheets, but not both simultaneously

Comment: @Nick http://imgur.com/gpQCJWN I changed the code slightly to show individual iterations in the screenshot. In the first link `k = 1 and l =3` (k and l corresponding to the rows and columns, respectively) selects the value **Arsenal (Home) vs Cardiff (Away)** in the matrix, highlighted. In the following link http://imgur.com/VOihxF0 'k = 1 and l = 2` which is for the value **Arsenal (Home) vs Aston Villa (Away)**. As you can imagine doing this iteration 20*20 times = 4000 times is onerous. This is what I meant about the results constantly changing when running it as a loop